# Moving one way in Europe

Tags: moving

I'm currently living in Switzerland though will be moving soon.

Perhaps to the UK, perhaps to Sweden...to where is not certain yet but there are many possibilities.

I do not have a car of my own however think the best way to do this move is by car/van- I have a significant amount of items, though not so much in the way of big furniture.

Were i just moving to Germany for instance there would be no issue. Rent and drop off a car as normal.

With this one way move I'm encountering difficulty however. A lot of companies claiming to do one way car rental which actually don't.

Does anyone know of any companies that might actually work for this?

Comment: When you ask for companies that might work for this, what is the "this"? One-way car rental from an unnamed town/city in Switzerland to an as-yet-unknown destination that could be anywhere within Europe? I suspect you'll have to narrow things down if you want to get a clear answer.

Comment: Not sure if this more suitable for Travel or Expats SE. Question sounds about relocation

Comment: Do companies specialise in Switzerland to Poland rental for example? 
I'm assuming if a company does one way rental in europe then it won't be so limited between two countries. So don't think its an issue that its vague- also good when asking questions not to be too broad so it can be relevant for others.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

- Hire a company to transport your stuff from where you live currently to your new home or
- Hire a car one-way and drive yourself

You will for sure find a car rental company that offers international one way rental, but they will add a charge as someone will have to drive the car back. It usually doesn't work for them to leave the car where you bring it and wait for another renter who will take it back, as frequently  the car rental offices are national franchises. (There are execptions. I once got a car with a German registration from Sixt in France.)

So basically you have to compare prices.

Depending on where to where you need to go, it may or it may not make sense to maybe take a train to the next larger city in Germany, hire a car there (inside the EU), drive to Switzerland to load your belongings, then drive from there to your EU destination.

When looking for a different solution than driving yourself, do not just ask removal companies. (They are known to be expensive as they work for people who don't pay off their own pocket most of the time.) There are sites on the Internet where you can look for freight capacities. You could just say: I have X boxes / euro paletts which need to go from A to B in between day X and day Y and you will receive offers. But this would mean you need to properly pack up your stuff, though it may be a cheap option.

When it comes to furniture, unless you live in very expensive designer furniture, in most cases selling your stuff off or just dumping it and buying new is the better option over transporting it anyway as you will find yourself replacing things in your new home which don't really fit or which got damanged somehow during the transport.

Comment: There's a third option: ship the items to the new location.  This is subtly different than hiring a moving company to transport them.  It often involves you boxing up the items and taking them to a shipping facility and the repeating then process in reverse at your destination.

Comment: Which car rental company workjs?
I tried sixt's site but every two destinations I put in between a variety of countries it tells me one way isn't available.

And yes. Renting from France or Germany is totally within my plan. The trouble is dropping  it back off in that country isn't really feasible assuming a distant move.